# concatenate rows of a filed to one string along with other fields in a join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have few tables

EMP

```
EmpCode, EmpName, Age
```

Attendance

```
AtCode, EmpCode, Sample1, Sample2
```

AnotherTable

```
id, EmpCode, Sample4, Sample5
```

Now my query is

```
SELECT distinct b.Sample4, e.EmpName, A.Sample1, A.Sample2 FROM  Attendance  A inner join
EMP e on a.EmpCode=e.EmpCode
left join AnotherTable b on A.EmpCode=b.EmpCode
```

This query results in following records

```
Sample4      EmpName    Sample1  Sample2
MG           Joy         01      11104
ST           Joy         01      11104
```

I need the result as

```
Sample4      EmpName    Sample1  Sample2
MG,ST            Joy         01      11104
```

How can we achieve this.

Comment: Which version you're using? You could use `STRING_AGG()` or `STUFF() and FOR XML PATH('')` with `GROUP BY`. There is a lot of posts on how to do this at least here in SO

Comment: @Sami I am usinf SQL Server 2014

Comment: I got confused when I have to join multiple tables